# Using MySql stored procedures for .NET Data Access Layer

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, stored-procedures, data-access-layer

I'm using .NET 2.0 and/or 3.5.  Weird thing is, everytime I add a query, whether via TableAdapter or a plain query in a Dataset, using a MySQL stored procedure (whether be a select, update, insert, delete), the wizard doesn't finish (the dialog suddenly disappears, I'm back to designer mode and the query isn't added to the tableadapter or dataset form).  Is there a special formatting required for MySQL stored procedures, or a workaround for MySQL stored procedures to work?

I'm using
MySQL 5.1.33
portable XAMPP 1.7.1
PHP 5.2.9
Apache 2.2.11
phpMyAdmin 3.1.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having this same thing happen.  The fix for me was the following: One of my parameters for the stored procedure was 'filter'. I changed it to 'p_filter' and the issue went away.  The issue that I am still dealing with is on the last screen of the filter I get:

you have an error in your sql syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your mysql server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1

I brought in a stored procedure that doesn't accept a parameter and I have no issues with creating the TableAdapter using the dataset wizard.